# Are these output streams possible?

Tags: lc3

I am working on a practice exam question

a
**The Problem**  A stack machine has the input stream of ABCD. Is it possible for an output stream of CDBA? For CDAB? Show the sequence of operations to create these streams or if not possible explain why it is not possible.

I said both output streams were possible.

For CDBA, here are my sequence of operations to create such a stream

1. push A
2. push B
3. push C
4. pop C/Store
5. push D

For CDAB

1. push A
2. pop A/store
3. push B
4. push A
5. push C
6. pop C / store
7. push D
8. push C

I assumed the stack machine works like a stack does -push pop. Does everyone agree with my two sequences of operations? Is there some property of a "stack machine" that makes these streams impossible to create/produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's still curious, I revisited this problem a couple of days ago. 
Basically you take in input into the stack machine via push and output via pop(the two principal operations)

So taking a look at our first input stream ABCD, here would be the sequence of operations to produce an output stream of CDBA

Push A

Push B

Push C

Pop C (Output Stream: C)

Push D

Pop D (Output Stream: CD)

Pop B (Output Stream: CDB)

Pop A (Output Stream: CDBA)

And thus an output stream of CDBA is formed

However to produce an output stream of CDAB, the first 6 operations from producing CDBA would apply to get an output stream of CD. However after those 6 operations, you were left with(from top to botto) ['B','A'] which means with just using push and pop, there is no way to output the A before the B.
Therefore the second output stream is not possible to form.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, everything looks good except you need to push C again at then end of CDBA.

Comment: yea thats what I thought so too but if you look at my answer, it shows why the second isn't possible.